# Change Cursor Using Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have a toolbox on my page that has several mouse cursor images. Is it possible to change the mouse cursor based on the image I select using jQuery or perhaps Javascript?

When I say change the mouse cursor, I'm not talking about just hovering over the mouse cursor image in the toolbox but make the mouse cursor appear and persist while the mouse cursor is being dragged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OP wants it only when the cursor is being dragged.

Comment: May be you want [ondrag](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjJ28GMuN3PAhVJWywKHRMpBTAQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FEvents%2Fdrag&usg=AFQjCNEBap-p8sUHkzPWucRMJTav2pHrKg&sig2=rmXLb-LjX36nTJx7FgOkdw&cad=rjt) event?

Comment: @ahitt6345 Well, OP can check my link and try coding it. Then come back with some code to work with.